# How can I add an image to an ExtendedFloatingActionButton (in addition of the icon)?

Tags: android, material-design, material-components-android, material-components

Is there a way to reproduce the following behavior using com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton ?

[image: Image from Material Desing]

I already have the right icon/shape/color but I can't find a way to make the same component as on the picture. The behavior expected and the screenshot come from https://material.io/components/sheets-bottom/#expanding-bottom-sheet.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same result with [this](https://github.com/HeyAlex/CornerSheet) library. Or just make the same [CornerSheetBehavior](https://github.com/HeyAlex/CornerSheet/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/google/android/material/bottomsheet/CornerMaterialSheetBehavior.kt)

The idea is taken from [material sample](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android-examples/blob/develop/Owl/app/src/main/java/com/materialstudies/owl/ui/lessons/LessonsSheetFragment.kt). You just need a *BottomShetBehavior* and change **traslationX** of view depends on slideOffset from *BottomSheetCallback*

Comment: This is an interesting library. But in fact my question is more about how to add a thumbnail image in the corner (not an icon) and not really about how to achieve BottomSheet. Is there a way to achieve what I want with this library ?